# JAXB marshalling problem - probably namespace related

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Given the intitial XML (BPEL) file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<process
    name="TestSVG2"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <sequence>
        <receive name="Receive1" createInstance="yes"/>
        <assign name="Assign1"/>
        <invoke name="Invoke1"/>
        <assign name="Assign2"/>
        <reply name="Reply1"/>
    </sequence>
</process>
```

I have written a function that uses JAXB in order to modify some data inside the XML.
The function is as follows:

```
public void editAction(String name, String newName) {
    Process proc;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
    Unmarshaller unMarsh = null;
    Object obj = new Object();
    try {
        /* XML TO JAVA OBJECT */
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.example");
        unMarsh = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        obj = unMarsh.unmarshal(new File(path + "/resources/" + BPELFilename));
        proc = (Process) obj;
        Process.Sequence sequence = proc.getSequence();

        /* Determine which element needs to be edited */
       /* Do some editing , code wasn't included */

        /* OBJ Back to XML */
        Marshaller marsh = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marsh.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        //marsh.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new CustomPrefixMapper());
        marsh.marshal(obj, new File(path + "/resources/" + BPELFilename));

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        /* Be afraid */
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The resulting XML after the JAXB-related editing is:

```
<!-- After -->
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:process 
    name="TestSVG2" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org">

    <ns0:sequence>
        <ns0:receive name="newName" createInstance="yes"/>
        <ns0:assign name="Assign1"/>
        <ns0:assign name="Assign2"/>
        <ns0:invoke name="Invoke1"/>
        <ns0:reply name="Reply1"/>
    </ns0:sequence>
</ns0:process>
```

Unfortunately the resulting XML, is not compliant to our application, as our XML parser crashes when is parsing the new XML.

So:

- How do I remove the namespace `ns0`, in the resulting XML ?
- How to I preserve the same header from the initial XML File (the `xml:xsd` is missing)?

Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed in your code you create an instance of JAXBContext on each call to "editActition".  JAXBContext is thread safe so you can create this once and then re-use that instance.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan Thanks Blaise. This function is part of a prototype. We are evaluating different libraries, and we come to JAXB. This is not a 'real' project. But I will certainly consider your observation.

Comment: I think you will find JAXB to be the strongest XML binding library.  I am a member of the JAXB expert group and lead the MOXy JAXB implementation.  Feel free to post questions here or contact me blaise.doughan@gmail.com if you have JAXB questions during your evaluation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to customize the namespace prefix that JAXB uses when marshalling to a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982977/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-namespace-prefix-that-jaxb-uses-when-marshalling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [MOXy JAXB](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation you can do the following:

Your domain objects:

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Process {

}
```

Use that package annotation @XmlSchema

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://www.example.org", 
    xmlns = {
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "xsd", namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
    },
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example;
```

To use MOXy JAXB you need to add a jaxb.properties file in with your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

This will produce the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<process xmlns="http://www.example.org" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```