# JAXB is reading tagnames instead of values of tags

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Our code is reading tagnames in the xml file instead of values inside.
We tried to change the values in the tags but it does not help.
The o/p is the name of the tag instead of the value

```
java file:



    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

    import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.ObjectFactory;



    import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

    public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException{

LoginRequest url=null;
JAXBContext jbc=null;
Unmarshaller um=null;
FileInputStream fis=null;
 jbc= JAXBContext.newInstance(LoginRequest.class);
 um = jbc.createUnmarshaller();
 fis = new FileInputStream("maintenance_technicalinformationmsgs_v1.0.xml");
url = (LoginRequest)um.unmarshal(fis);
//url.setUserId("MARMIK");
System.out.println(url);
System.out.println(url.getUserId());
System.out.println(url.getLanguage());
System.out.println(url.getPassWord());
System.out.println(url.getMarket());
```

}

xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tns:LoginRequest xmlns:tns=**Namespace name 
    xmlns:tns1=** 
    xmlns:xsi=**
    xsi:schemaLocation=**Schema location
    >
   <tns:userId>tns:ud</tns:userId>
   <tns:passWord>tns:passord</tns:passWord>
   <tns:language>tns:language</tns:language>
   <tns:market>tns:market</tns:market>
   </tns:LoginRequest>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does you input document look like?

Comment: yea .. code looks like there is no problem.. check ur input and jaxb classes.

Comment: Try what is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3396923/1648446