# JAXB, xs:any and targetNamespace

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have an XSD that defines the following schema:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns="http://example.com/2010/aa/"
       xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
       xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
       xmlns:aa="http://example.com/2010/aa/"
       targetNamespace="http://example.com/2010/aa/"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">
...
<xs:element name="user" type="aa:User"/>
<xs:complexType name="User">
  <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="aa:firstName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="aa:lastName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      ...
      <xs:any namespace="##targetNamespace" processContents="skip" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="profile" type="aa:Profile"/>
<xs:complexType name="Profile">
 <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="aa:username" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element ref="aa:accountStatus" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element ref="aa:roleid" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    ...
    <xs:element ref="aa:userid"/>
 </xs:sequence>
 <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip" />
</xs:complexType>
```

When JAXB is marshalling the generated Objects it defines the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/2010/aa/">...</user>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<profile xmlns="http://example.com/2010/aa/">...</profile>
```

See how one namespace is **xmlns:ns2** and the other one is **xmlns**. This is because all the elements of user are qualified for the aa namespace but the ones defined by the **xs:any** tag, hence the need to define two namespaces.

Profile doesn't have a xs:any tag and doesn't need to define more than one namespaces. This is my interpretation, since if I remove the xs:any from the user definition it will remove the **ns2** from the generated XML.

How can I tell JAXB that both the **targetNamespace** and **aa** are the same namespace so it doesn't include both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use a `NamespacePrefixMapper` to override how the prefixes are generated in the first place:

```
NamespacePrefixMapper mapper = new NamespacePrefixMapper() {
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
        return "";
    }
};
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", mapper);
```

I'm returning `""` there, so there will be only a default prefix; implement a more sophisticated version as required.

This does create a dependency on a Sun class, which is a problem caused by JAXB. Please review [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289644/define-spring-jaxb-namespaces-without-using-namespaceprefixmapper). The answer at the bottom shows how to modify `package-info.java` to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, instead of using a proprietary [Metro JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) extension, you could use [MOXy JAXB](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  MOXy will use the namespace prefixing defined in the @XmlSchema package level annotation.

For more information see:

- [JAXB marshalling problem - probably namespace related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394644/jaxb-marshalling-problem-probably-namespace-related/3396923#3396923)
- [Jaxb2Marshaller creating JAXBContext with empty namespace URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333600/jaxb2marshaller-creating-jaxbcontext-with-empty-namespace-uri/3397260#3397260)
- [Define Spring JAXB namespaces without using NamespacePrefixMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289644/define-spring-jaxb-namespaces-without-using-namespaceprefixmapper/3291893#3291893)